# Why is my custom PermissionEvaluator not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I can’t understand why my security doesn’t work properly. Method hasPermission() in Evaluator class not even called. I think there is something wrong with my security config.

My Security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean:beans xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <sec:http use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
                        username-parameter="login"
                        password-parameter="password"
                        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                        authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"/>
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/WEB-INF/views/error/403.jsp"/>
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="userAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <bean:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <bean:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </bean:bean>

    <bean:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="de.mark.project.security.UserPermissionEvaluator">
        <bean:constructor-arg ref="userSecurityService"/>
    </bean:bean>

    <bean:bean id="successHandler" class="de.mark.project.security.UrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <bean:bean id="userSecurityService" class="de.mark.project.service.UserService"/>

    <bean:bean name="userAuthenticationProvider" class="de.mark.project.security.UserAuthenticationProvider">
        <bean:constructor-arg ref="userSecurityService"/>
    </bean:bean>

</bean:beans>
```

Here is my custom evaluator:

```
public class UserPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    private UserService service;

    @Autowired
    public UserPermissionEvaluator(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, 
                                 Serializable targetId,  String targetType, 
                                 Object permission) {

        UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        User authorizedUser = service.getUser(principal.getUsername());
        Collection<Permission> userPermissions = authorizedUser.getPermissions();

        for (Permission p : userPermissions) {
            if (p.getName().equals(allowedPermission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, 
                                 Serializable targetId,  String targetType, 
                                 Object permission) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error");
    }
}
```

Method in the controller which using security:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(null, 'create_user')")
public String createUserForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    return "user/internal/form/credentialForm";
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

UPD:

```
<web-app
        version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <!-- log4j configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Config Setup -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/spring-config/security.xml
            classpath:/spring-config/data.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/spring-config/mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Error handling -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

UPD 2

Spring MVC config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="de.mark.project.web"/>
    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/style/"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that the `<global-method-security>` tag needs to be in the same context as your Spring MVC configuration otherwise your controllers will not be post processed. This is [discussed in the FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context).

So for example, if your web.xml looks like the following:

```
<!--
  - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context
  - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
  -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--
  - Loads the root application context of this web app at startup.
  - The application context is then available via
  - WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext).
-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc/*.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

To support method security on your controllers ensure the `<global-method-security>` tag is defined in a location within /WEB-INF/mvc/*.xml. Note that the remainder of the configuration should remain where it is. If you want to support method security on your services, you likely also need `<global-method-security>` in the parent (i.e. where it likely is now).

If this does not help, please post your web.xml or WebApplicationInitializer's if you are not using web.xml

Comment: Please also post updated /spring-config/mvc.xml (ensure it contains `<global-method-security>` in it).

Comment: I added mvc.xml. But now in my UserController disappeared all mapping (no viewresolvers found).

Comment: Try using `<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />` http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-global-method-security-proxy-target-class

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I've got: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Duplicate <global-method-security> detected.
Offending resource: file [...blahblah...\WEB-INF\classes\spring-config\security.xml]

Comment: blah blah blah is important :) Please post the full stack. Also make sure you wire in your PermissionEvaluator in the mvc.xml

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. The problem was solved by moving <sec:global-method-security> with permissionEvaluator bean from security.xml to mvc.xml. Now it works fine. Although I think that it is no good solution to store security stuff in mvc.xml