# Spring security hasPermission is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Spring Security in my spring web application. Basically I need to hide some menus based on user permission. Here is what I did.

I added below JARS in classpath.

```
spring-security-acl-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
```

Below are the entries in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/web_log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-root.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I wrote a class CustomPermissionEvaluator like below.

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator{


@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) targetDomainObject;
    Profile userProfile = (Profile) request.getSession().getAttribute("testprofile");
    if (userProfile.getPermissionMap().get(String.valueOf(permission)) != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1,
        String arg2, Object arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

After this I wrote SecurityConfig file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
    web.expressionHandler(handler);
}
```

}

I have below entries in my spring-root.xml

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>
<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
</bean>
<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="main.java.com.config.CustomPermissionEvaluator" />
```

Now in my JSP file I am using below taglib.

and below code

```
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission('cadastra_categoria', #request)">      
                <div id="TEST">
                </div>
            </sec:authorize>
```

But it is not working. Any suggesation will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an indicator, error or something? Does the hasPermission call reached the implementation when you place a breakpoint? I think you are missing the security filterchain https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml but its an assumption

Comment: No, neither I am getting any error nor call reaching to CustomPermissionEvaluator .

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing your bean correctly? `class="main.java.com.config.CustomPermissionEvaluator"` - shouldn't this be without `main.java`?

Comment: @aturkovic yes I am referring my bean correctly. That is how project is.

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging to see if your evaluation is really called? Also, some logging for debugging and to see if you encounter any exception?

Comment: @N4zroth CustomPermissionEvaluator is being loaded by spring. That I confirmed by putting loggers. But it is not being called when I am calling it from JSP using spring security tag.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974926/how-configure-the-spring-security-to-allow-the-use-for-haspermission-in-the-jsp

Comment: @AmitKBist I already checked that. Not working for me.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386675/why-is-my-custom-permissionevaluator-not-working

Comment: did you check with list of permission set properly in `CustomPermissionEvaluator` that you created?

Answer (score 2):

> "hasPermission('cadastra_categoria', #request)"

Actually, valid call has to have arguments swapped, first one must be target domain object and second - permission:

```
hasPermission(#request, 'cadastra_categoria')
```

I assume you also double-checked you've imported `sec` taglib to your JSP as required

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

And finally as clarified in 2-nd part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065208/8513835), define the following:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {
      SecurityConfig.class //your SecurityConfig
    };
  }
}
```

to make sure `configure(WebSecurity web)` is called during your web application startup

Comment: Leave it guys I solved my problem yesterday and will update with solution. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

As i understand your question you have created `CustomPermissionEvaluator` class but you are not checking with your Authenticated user permission.

I am directly writing the code **`CustomPermissionEvaluator`** for clear my point there might be any error:

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        if ((auth == null) || (targetDomainObject == null) || !(permission instanceof String)){
            return false;
        }

        Profile userProfile = (Profile) request.getSession().getAttribute("testprofile");
        String targetType = userProfile.getPermissionMap().get(String.valueOf(permission));

        return hasPrivilege(auth, targetType, permission.toString().toUpperCase());
    }

    private boolean hasPrivilege(Authentication auth, String targetType, String permission) {
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuth : auth.getAuthorities()) {
            if (grantedAuth.getAuthority().startsWith(targetType)) {
                if (grantedAuth.getAuthority().contains(permission)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try hasAnyRole and check once i.e

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_NAME')"> TEST </sec:authorize>
```